# how to pass parsed xml into core-data object

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I am currently setting up core-data into my application that I have already started, I have all of the core data delegates set up and have completed everything in [this](http://wiresareobsolete.com/2009/12/adding-core-data-existing-iphone-projects/) tutorial.

I already have my `NSXMLParser` delegates working separately to my core data (currently I am caching the results etc etc.) but now I would like to pass all of the parsed data into the coredata object, but I have no idea where to start.

This is what my `parserDidEndDocument` looks like, I think I pass the parsed data through to my code data in here?

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    if (dataSetToParse == @"ICMfg") 
    {
       //Filter results (ISVEHICLE = T)
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@",@"ISVEHICLE",@"T"];
        NSArray *filteredArray = [myDataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        //Passes Manufacturer strigs over to startSortingtheArray method
        [self startSortingTheArray:[filteredArray valueForKey:@"MANUFACTURER"]];

        //Loading Messages etc
        [self scrollToRowAtIndexPath];
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(stopAnimating) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }
    //...etc
```

The data set I want to parse is ICMFg (thats the xml I am parsing).. so do I, and if I do would I pass the data over to the core-data from here? or am I wrong. 
also once the data is in the core data.. if the user tries to reload the list again later on how do I call from core data instead of parsing?

I have been looking around the net for examples but thought someone might be able to help here.. I will keep looking but I just not to sure about how it works with me because I am adding core data to my app after I have already started...

Answer (score 0):

Create your coreData model (that is, what the class you will save look like). Then generate the class files. To do that, follow this simple [tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/).

When you are done, just create a new instance of the class, with your data inside, and call save on it, (it is in the tuto too).

Good luck!

Comment: cheers will have a look at it now :) man I wish I had have selected this from the very beginning lol.

Comment: Yeah this tutorial is pretty cool :). tell me if it goes right!